# Execute a code only for the first time logged in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am coding a user registration and login system with PHP. Actually, I could make them work already.

The thing is that I want the user to fill a form but only the first time the user has logged in the page (this is because the results from the form will determine some preferences in the system and I want the user to take the test only once)

Could you guys help me with the logic please?

Comment: database flag on the user, has_logged_in - default 0, after first log in set it to 1, check it and switch logic as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new field in the database, form_submitted and give it false when a new users registers. Turn it to true after he submits the form. If the value is true, dont show him the form.

Comment: I am really glad! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a new column to the users' table. for example 
Tbl_user (username,password,status)

You can update tbl_user's status.

for instance:

The user clicked the submit button in fill up form.

the update your status:

```
UPDATE tbl_user SET status='fill' WHERE username=$_SESSION['username']
```

now you can select it:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE status!='fill'
```